# Make image link to a page using Logo Attributes in Oracle APEX

Tags: html, oracle, oracle-apex

I'm currently running Oracle Applications Express on my corporate network (for an internal project) and I am simply trying to make the Logo that I have used to link to the home page. The logo appears on every page and when a user clicks on the logo, it navigates them back to the home page.

I've tried all sorts of different strings, like

```
$('a[href*="HOME"]')
<a href="/">
<a href="f?p=300">
```

etc. etc.

My application is lying on Application 300, since this is the development version. The home URL is: `f?p=300:1:17112837468263`

Is what I am asking actually possible to do?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you define the logo on the application attributes, it will be shown on pages because it has been included in the page template(s).
For example, on my apex (4.2) instance I'm using "Theme 24 - Cloudy". In the "One Level Tabs - No Sidebar" template the logo substitution string `#LOGO#` is used in the "Definition > Body" section:

```
<header id="uHeader">
  #REGION_POSITION_07#
  <hgroup>
    <a href="#HOME_LINK#" id="uLogo">#LOGO#</a>
    <div class="uAPEXNavBar">
      <ul>
        #NAVIGATION_BAR#
      </ul>
    </div>
    #REGION_POSITION_08#
  </hgroup>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      #TAB_CELLS#
    </ul>
  </nav>
  #REGION_POSITION_04#
</header>
#REGION_POSITION_01#
#SUCCESS_MESSAGE##NOTIFICATION_MESSAGE##GLOBAL_NOTIFICATION#
<div id="uOneCol">
  #REGION_POSITION_02#
  #BOX_BODY#
  #REGION_POSITION_03#
</div>
```

header > hgroup > a if you didn't spot it.

As you can see, the logo here is already wrapped in an anchor which refers to the homelink `#HOME_LINK#`. This homelink is something you can define aswell by the way. You can set the homelink through "Application Properties > User interfaces" and selecting the interface you use, for example "Desktop". "Home URL" is a field there.

So what you should do is:

- Check the theme you are using
- Check the default page template (and any other used page templates of
  course)
- See where the `#LOGO#` substitution string is used and how it is put
  out

If it isn't in an anchor yet you can do that. If you aren't on apex 4.2 (You didn't specify) I'm not sure if you can use `#HOME_LINK#`, I can't recall. You could always use string substitution syntax however (and you should, especially when constructing these types of links): `href='f?p=&APP_ID.:1:&SESSION.'`